# Compare files .class Beyond Compare 4

Tags: java, war, .class-file, beyondcompare4

I'm using Beyond Compare 4 (4.1.9) in order to compare war files.

I need to compare the files *.class* that I find in the several packages.

1. How I can compare them using this product (Beyond Compare 4)?
2. Otherwise there is another product which can *compare* war file and compile the .class files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Double clicking on a war file in Beyond Compare's folder compare will expand it as a folder because war files are essentially zip files.

To decompile Java class files to source code in Beyond Compare, install the **Java Class to Source** file format. With the file format installed, when you double click on a .class file inside a .war archive, it will display the decompiled source code in Beyond Compare's Text Compare.

Download page for file formats:
http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_moreformatsv4

Note the Java class to source file format is only available for Windows, it isn't available for the Linux or Mac versions of Beyond Compare.

Answer (score 4):

1. Download **Java Class to Source** file format from  http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_moreformatsv4
2. In Beyond Compare, **pick Tools | Import Settings**.
3. Fill in the downloaded filename, and click Next and proceed to finish.

Answer (score 2):

Option : javap -l -p -c -constants %s > %t 2>&1 : doesn't work for me on beyondCompare4 4.3.7 (latest version to this date), and if used directly through cmd, gives a .class output but the formatting is bad and it is not really interpretable for the java reader I am.

Option to download the format through  http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_moreformatsv4 : doesn't work for me neither. This library is based http://varaneckas.com/jad which is quite old.

The option I recommend and that worked is :
Download https://github.com/kwart/jd-cli (project based from the famous "Java Decompiler" or "jd-gui" as we know it). Once it is installed, do the following in BeyondCompare4 :
Go in format, create a new format, use external program, and use the following :
C:\Users%USERNAME%\jd-cli-1.2.0-dist\jd-cli.bat %s > %t 2>&1

Hope this will help some.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the need to compare class files in Beyond Compare 4 and so I found that adding an external program and using `javap -l -p -c -constants %s > %t 2>&1` was enough for me. Just make sure a reasonably recent `javap` is one the PATH that understands any of the class file formats you'd want to compare. No extra software required and is cross platform compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The link to more formats is old in the above answer.
Here use this one.

https://www.scootersoftware.com/kb/moreformats

1. Download Java Class to Source file format from https://www.scootersoftware.com/kb/moreformats
2. In Beyond Compare, pick Tools | Import Settings.
3. Fill in the downloaded filename, and click Next and proceed to finish.